# Appropriate way to hide/show individual series

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js, what's the most appropriate way to hide/show different series in, say, a multi-series time series chart?

1. Bind my data to an `<svg>` element, then each time I render, select a subset of that data and bind to my `<path>` elements.
2. Attach the data to a javascript variable (global?) and then pass subsets of it to my `chart()` object.
3. Others?